# R - How do I plot down core data in R?

Tags: r, plot

What I have:

> Abundance values of microfossils A, B, and C
>
> Depth of sediment core 0-130cm.

What I want to accomplish:

> Plot in a line graph the abundance values of A, B, and C in one x-axis along the depth of 0-130cm such that the y-axis is downwards from 0 to -130 (not upwards 0 to +130).
>
> What I want to show is how the abundances of microfossils A, B, C varies as I go deeper along the length of the sediment core.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also used random data. Is this what you're looking for?

```
dat <- data.frame(depth = seq(0,130, by = 10), abundance = sample(100, size = 14*3, replace = TRUE), sp = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 14))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = abundance, y = depth, colour = sp)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_path() +
  scale_y_reverse()
```

In principle plotting downcode data is the same as a normal scatter or line plot.

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU! This is exactly what I'm looking for. As I'm new to R and wanted to learn, I've been trying to figure this out for almost the whole day. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide data and didn't say which kind of plot you'd like to create, you might have to reshape your data structure and adjust the code that creates the plot.
Here's an example using `ggplot2` in order to create a barplot. Please note that I used some random numbers in this example.

```
library(ggplot2)

# sample data
x <- data.frame(microfossil = c("A", "B", "C"),
           AV = c(20,50,80),
           depth=c(10,56,125))

# plot
ggplot(x, aes(AV, -depth, fill=microfossil))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity")+

  # adjust the y-axis
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                     limits = c(-130,0),
                     breaks = seq(-130,0,10))
```

As you can see, the y-axis goes from 0 down to -130 and the bars are directed downwards. This is done by just putting a minus in front of your y-variable, i.e. `-depth`. I then adjusted the y-axis a bit so that it's visually more appealing.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying. I'm trying to make a down core scatter plot like this one: I'm trying to make a line graph like the one in the middle in this link: http://www-odp.tamu.edu/publications/204_IR/chap_10/c10_f17.htm. Thanks in advance.

I edited my question to be clearer.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes it a lot clearer what you want to achieve. However, there's already a pretty good answer here, so I'll leave mine as it is.